# In shell how do I initialize array with zeros equal to length of another array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

for example the second line I want to do dynamically based on length of first:

```
DOMAINS=("gmail.com" "yahoo.com" "yahoo.co.uk" "yahoo.co.jp")
s_domain=(0 0 0 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

At least in recent bash versions, you can apply parameter expansions element-wise to an array:

```
s_domain=("${DOMAINS[@]/*/0}")
```

ex.

```
$ DOMAINS=("gmail.com" "yahoo.com" "yahoo.co.uk" "yahoo.co.jp")
$ s_domain=("${DOMAINS[@]/*/0}")
$ printf '%s\n' "${s_domain[@]}"
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop:

```
for i in "${DOMAINS[@]}"; do s_domain+=(0); done
```

Comment: A good answer, but note that this does not guarantee that each of the indices of $s_domain match the indices of $DOMAINS, only that the total number of elements is the same.